# Why is Sarah not mentioned in either Terah or Haran's Toledoth in Genesis 11?

Tags: genesis, chronology, abraham

When Abraham is accosted by Abimelech king of Gerah concerning Sarah he claims that she is his sister from his father's side

Genesis 20:12 NASB

> Besides, she actually is my sister, the daughter of my father, but not the daughter of my mother; and she became my wife;

When looking at toledoths in the book of Genesis beginning with that of Nahor the father of Terah we find out that it clearly states that besides his sons there were also daughters born to him

Genesis 11:24 NASB

> Nahor lived twenty-nine years, and fathered Terah; 25 and Nahor lived 119 years after he fathered Terah, and he fathered other sons and daughters.

But when we get to Terah's toledoth it is only stated that he had three sons namely Abraham,Nahor and Haran and there is no mention of any daughters

Genesis 11:26 NASB

> Terah lived seventy years, and fathered Abram, Nahor, and Haran.

Even when we look further at Haran's toledoth it mentions only one son and no daughter

Genesis 11:27 NASB

> Now these are the records of the generations of Terah. Terah fathered Abram, Nahor, and Haran; and Haran fathered Lot.

NB:Why I included Haran's toledoth is because some have reckoned that Sarah was actually his daughter and sister to Lot.

Why was Sarah not mentioned in either Terah or Haran's toledoth?

Comment: We are not told.  So we do not know.  Genealogies are often quite selective and seldom exhaustive/complete.

Answer (score 1):

We are not told so we do not know, as @Dottard commented. But this pattern of being selective also occurs with Haran's toledoth omitting Milcah, but we find out two verses later about her.

Genesis 11:29 KJV:

> And Abram and Nahor took them wives: the name of Abram’s wife was
> Sarai; and the name of Nahor’s wife, Milcah, the daughter of Haran,
> the father of Milcah, and the father of Iscah.